# How to limit the time range in datepair.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to limit the time range like the minimum hours will be 3 and the maximum is 6 hours. Like it will disable the 6.5 hrs and below as well in 3 hrs minimum.

[image: This is the sample image]

```js
$('#timeOnlyExample .time').timepicker({
  'showDuration': true,
  'timeFormat': 'g:i A',
  minTime: '06:00:00',
  maxTime: '23:00:00'
});

var timeOnlyExampleEl = document.getElementById('timeOnlyExample');
var timeOnlyDatepair = new Datepair(timeOnlyExampleEl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepair.js/0.4.16/datepair.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepair.js/0.4.16/jquery.datepair.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="timeOnlyExample">
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
 <label>Date</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control time start" name="rstart" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
 <label>Date</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control time end" name="rend" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set the minimum time by overriding `Datepair.prototype._updateEndMintime`.

I just created a delta setting called `minEndTimeDelta`. You can probably do something similar to the `maxEndTime`. This only covers fixing the starting hour for the end time.

```js
baseTime.setTime(baseTime.getTime() + this.parseTimeAsMillis(this.settings.minEndTimeDelta));
```

```js
timeOnlyDatepair.settings = Object.assign(timeOnlyDatepair.settings, {
  minEndTimeDelta: '03:00' // End time is +3 hours from start time
});
```

```js
let delta = this.parseTimeAsMillis(this.settings.minEndTimeDelta) - HOURS_MILLIS;
newTime.setTime(newTime.getTime() + delta)
this.settings.updateTime(input, newTime);
```

If you want the ending hour for the end time to be `<= 6` hours, you will need to fix `jquery.timepicker.js`, but this may be trickier because they are private.

e.g.

```js
function _render(self) {
  // ...stuff
  if (end < start) {
    end += _ONE_DAY; // Change to _ONE_DAY / 4 or make it a setting?
  }
  if (end === _ONE_DAY-1 && $.type(settings.timeFormat) === "string" && settings.show2400) {
    end = _ONE_DAY; // Change to _ONE_DAY / 4 or make it a setting?
  }
  // ...more stuff
}
```

You could also dynamically update the `settings.maxTime` to always be 6 hours ahead of the start time, but you may not be able to utilize the date rollover feature, not sure of this...

### Example

```js
const SECONDS_MILLIS = 1000;
const MINUTES_MILLIS = 60 * SECONDS_MILLIS;
const HOURS_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTES_MILLIS;
const TIME_MAP = [ HOURS_MILLIS, MINUTES_MILLIS, SECONDS_MILLIS ];

/* This is a new method created by me, that I added to the Datepair proto.
 * @param time {string} - Time in the format "hh:mm"
 * @return Returns the time in milliseconds.
 */
Datepair.prototype.parseTimeAsMillis = function(time) {
  return time.split(':').reduce((m, t, i) => m + (parseInt(t, 10) * TIME_MAP[i]), 0);
};

/* @Override */
Datepair.prototype._updateEndMintime = function() {
  if (typeof this.settings.setMinTime != 'function') return;
  var baseTime = null;
  if (this.settings.anchor == 'start' &&
    (!this.dateDelta || this.dateDelta < _ONE_DAY ||
      (this.timeDelta && this.dateDelta + this.timeDelta < _ONE_DAY))) {
    baseTime = this.settings.parseTime(this.startTimeInput);
    baseTime.setTime(baseTime.getTime() + this.parseTimeAsMillis(this.settings.minEndTimeDelta));
  }
  this.settings.setMinTime(this.endTimeInput, baseTime);
};

/* @Override */
Datepair.prototype._setTimeAndReturn = function(input, newTime) {
  let delta = this.parseTimeAsMillis(this.settings.minEndTimeDelta) - HOURS_MILLIS;
  newTime.setTime(newTime.getTime() + delta)
  this.settings.updateTime(input, newTime);
  return this.settings.parseTime(input);
};

$('#timeOnlyExample .time').timepicker({
  showDuration: true,
  timeFormat: 'g:i A',
  minTime: '06:00:00',
  maxTime: '23:00:00'
});

var timeOnlyExampleEl = document.getElementById('timeOnlyExample');
var timeOnlyDatepair = new Datepair(timeOnlyExampleEl);

timeOnlyDatepair.settings = Object.assign(timeOnlyDatepair.settings, {
  minEndTimeDelta: '03:00' // End time is +3 hours from start time
});

//$('#timeOnlyExample .time').on('change.datepair', function(e) {
//  $('.ui-timepicker-with-duration .ui-timepicker-list li').each((index, li) => {
//    console.log($(li).text());
//  });
//});
```

```css
.ui-timepicker-wrapper.ui-timepicker-with-duration ul {
  background: #FFE;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Timepicker -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Datepicker -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Datepair -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepair.js/0.4.16/datepair.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepair.js/0.4.16/jquery.datepair.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="timeOnlyExample">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label>Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control time start" name="rstart" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label>Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control time end" name="rend" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It may help you. https://timepicker.co/options/

Try with `minTime` and `maxHour`.

Comment: OP used `minTime`, that is for BOTH drop-downs.